# how to use union tool for merging more than two layers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, merge, union

I want to combine different layers into one but I still want to identify different layers in the new combined layer. Union is best for this, but it doesn't allow me to combine more than two layers. I am using arcgis 10.1, with site license.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to let us know what software, software version, and license level you're using?

Answer (score 5):

You say that you are using a "site license" but not whether your license level of **ArcGIS for Desktop** is **Basic**, **Standard** or **Advanced**.

If it is **Advanced** then **[Union](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000s000000)** will allow you to use more than two input feature classes.

If it is **Basic** or **Standard** then you will need to do pair-wise Unions and then Union the results instead.

To have the original FID for all feature classes preserved in the final output you should use **ALL** for **join_attributes**.

Comment: I have basic license. I tried pair-wise union, but that didn't work for me when I wanted to recombine the paired layers again using 'union'. I have unique attribute values in each different layers, I need to combine them by attribute so that I can still identify which layer they belong to after combining. Is there an easier or alternative way to do this?

Comment: @user27321 Did you use ALL for join_attributes?  The other two options will lose the original FIDs during or after the first Union respectively.

Comment: If you want to retain FIDs I would suggest copying them to an FID2 field first, FIDs are not guaranteed to be consistent after data is edited.

Comment: @AnserGIS you are right ***if the data is edited*** but this Question is only about whether Union-ing multiple feature classes can retain links through to the original feature classes.

Comment: Fortunately, I had advanced license and could run 'union' for multiple layers. That didn't completely solve my problem as union was not done based on a intended field. I had to copy/paste and modify fields later on attribute table.