# Simultaneous multiple vector layer intersection algorithm

Tags: geoprocessing, vector, algorithm

Is there an algorithm, you can suggest or recommend, that I can implement to intersect multiple vector layers?

I have a few hundred layers I want to intersect and thinking of developing a little QGIS python script to solve it (it doesn't have to be QGIS). All the layers are of the same geometric type of either polyline or polygon.

I am aware that I can intersect them two at a time but perhaps it's more efficient to implement a mechanism that intersects all these layers at the same time?

Comment: If you have access to ArcGis and an advanced license you can do as many layers as a python string will hold with Union/Identity/Intersect tools. What sort of 'intersect' are you after? Union, clip, erase..

Comment: This is a similar question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87588/how-to-use-union-tool-for-merging-more-than-two-layers A while ago I looked into the Python code needed to specify the necessary pair-wise polygon overlays using some "tennis tournament" algorithms from [so] but I ran out of time on the task I needed it for before I got it working.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I do have access to advanced ArcGIS license; however, for this project, I'm interested in doing it in QGIS

Comment: @PolyGeo Feel free to answer with some of the resources you have and I can perhaps take that role on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to use a Basic level license of ArcGIS for Desktop to perform intersections (or other polygon overlays like Union) between more than two input feature classes I would recommend performing them pair-wise i.e. for four input feature classes intersect the first two, then intersect the other two, before intersecting the preceding results.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792213/algorithm-for-generating-a-bracket-model-list-in-python is a Q&A that I think was the one that was investigating a while ago to write a Python script to use an input list of feature classes and perform the minimum number of necessary intersections to have them all intersected.  Unfortunately, I did not complete that script, and no longer have a copy of where I got up to, because I was onsite with a short deadline.

Comment: Nice! especially with that link to bracket modelling. When your only choice is a + b = c like QGIS or Esri with basic/standard license that would be the only way. So a + b = c, d + e = f then f + c = answer for a 4 dataset overlay... extrapolate the pairs like a tournament.

Comment: Don't worry, I started to comment "Good point @ChrisW" before re-thinking, and its only mid-afternoon here,

Comment: Other than your solution, is there an actual algorithm that someone can implement? I guess what I mean is that your solution seems to be a workaround rather than an actual solution if that makes any sense

Comment: As far as I know the internals of Esri's polygon overlay algorithms are not available anywhere. You might be able to write some ArcPy to use its geometry operators but I suspect it would be far slower and more complicated than pair-wise intersects or using Advanced.

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo, as I said before, I do have access to ArcGIS Advanced; however, I was hoping to do something with QGIS. I'll test the pairwise this week and see what I can come up with